# GDC installation error

Tags: gcc, d

I wanted to install GDC at my FreeBSD Desktop, so I followed this:
https://wiki.dlang.org/GDC/Installation/Generic

I typed those at my tcsh terminal:

```
vmware@localhost:~ % sudo mkdir -p gdc/dev
vmware@localhost:~ % sudo cp Downloads/gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz gdc
vmware@localhost:~ % cd gdc
vmware@localhost:~/gdc % sudo tar -xvf gcc-7.3.0.tar.xz
vmware@localhost:~/gdc % sudo git clone https://github.com/D-Programming-GDC/GDC.git dev
vmware@localhost:~/gdc % cd dev
vmware@localhost:~/gdc/dev % sudo git checkout gdc-7
vmware@localhost:~/gdc/dev % sudo ./setup-gcc.sh ../gcc-7.3.0
vmware@localhost:~/gdc/dev % sudo mkdir ../objdir
vmware@localhost:~/gdc/dev % cd ../objdir
```

these didn't made any errors.
but when I typed this,

```
vmware@localhost:~/gdc/objdir % sudo ../gcc-7.3.0/configure --enable-languages=d --disable-bootstrap --prefix=/usr/local/share/gdc --with-bugurl="http://bugzilla.gdcproject.org" --enable-checking=yes
```

terminal said:

```
configure: error: GDC is required to build d
```

why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

GDC has been updated to now use the D frontend (v2.081.1). See https://github.com/D-Programming-GDC/GDC/commit/1c2972f44660d64173202a7f111bd915a578700c. This means a GDC bootstrap compiler will be needed to build GDC.

After discussing this with some of the GDC developers, this is my understanding of their strategy:

- `stable` and `gdc-x-stable` branches will continue to use the C++ frontend, so they will not require a GDC bootstrap compiler.
- `master` and `gdc-x` branches will use the D frontend, so will require a GDC bootstrap compiler

So, I believe the procedure would be

1. build a bootstrap compiler from `gdc-x-stable` branch
2. Use the bootstrap compiler from (1) to build `gdc-x` branch
3. Perhaps use the resulting GDC compiler from (2) to build the `gdc-x` branch again.